# Godot 4 сделал щит который окружает игрока, но его коллизия не работает

Tags: godot

Нужно, чтобы щит окружил игрока и не пропускал никого, по идее это `$hitbox.disabled = false`, но она не работает
При нажатии добавляется сцена щита

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("pressed"):
        var shield_area = load("res://Scenes/Shield.tscn").instantiate()
        get_parent().add_child(shield_area)
        shield_area.position.x = position.x
        shield_area.position.y = position.y
        protection = true
else:
        protection = false
```

Вот сам скрипт щита

```
extends Area2D

var damaged = false
var hp = 10

func _ready():
    $Timer.start(1)

func _process(delta):
    pass


func _on_timer_timeout():
    get_parent().remove_child(self)
    queue_free()
```

Сцена
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Коллизия у всех объектов в layer и mask = 1